# What data structure can I use for fast lookup to check that a key does not exist in a table?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I want a data structure that I can use to check that a key does not exist in a table. I'm only interested in lookup, and I want the data structure to be optimized to search for keys not in the table. That is, determining that a key does not exist should be a very fast operation.

Comment: This is called the set membership problem. There are many possibilities with different advantages and disadvantages. A big part of deciding the best option is the type and size of the keys. Also the number of keys, how often the table changes, etc. You need to add more details about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to store a table of say forbidden queries. i.e Strings. When I receive a receive a query, I lookup it up in the table to see if it forbidden, if it is not, we proceed to search for it.